# Adding Inbound nat pool to existing scale set

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm-scale-set

I've created an inbound NAT pool in a specific load balancer. I want to add this inbound NAT pool to an existing virtual machine scale set ip configuration. How is that possible? I don't seem to find how I can edit already existing configuration.

Comment: When you create a VMSS a LB and NAT rules are automatically created. Can you elaborate on your situation and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a VMSS that was probably created from a template (I'm didn't create it), It doens't have a load balancer attached to it. Now I want to expose the scale set to the "internet" that I could be able to access internal VM's ports. What I did is I created a new load balancer with a public ip, created a backend pool and attached it to the vmss. I've also created an inbound NAT pool in the load balancer, with the specific rdp port. However from what I understand and see, it doesn't automatically add the pool I've created to the VMSS ip configuration..

Comment: It cannot automatically add the rules for the vmss if you do not create the load balancer in the creation time. So you need to add the rules manually as I said in the answer.

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 1):

The resources load balancer and the virtual machine scale set are the associated relationship. What you can do is add the virtual machine scale set into the backend pool of the load balancer, and then you can change the existing NAT rules or create new rules to associate with the instance of the existing scale set.

In addition, when you create the virtual machine scale set, there also a configuration to select the load balancer or application gateway for it, if you select load balancer, Azure will add the NAT rules for you. It shows like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the example for "update the load balancer of your scale set" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-upgrade-scale-set#examples. This walks through how to remove an existing load balancer from a scale set and add a new one in its place. When you update the IpConfiguration for the scale set, it should create the necessary rules for you. If you're still having trouble connecting to VMs in the scale set, check the following common issues:

- If the scale set is in "manual" update mode, then you'll need to bring all of the VMs up to date with the model (also discussed in the above doc) for the new networking changes to take effect.
- If you're using SLB Standard, you need to whitelist traffic with a network security group (with SLB Standard, by default all traffic is disallowed).

Best of luck! :)